# Is Queue.foreach properly ordered?

Tags: scala, foreach, queue

Will the `foreach` method of a Scala immutable Queue always be processed in the order one expects for a queue or is there a method that guarantees the order? Or do I have to use a loop + `dequeue`?

Answer (score 7):

`scala.collection.immutable.Queue` is `scala.collection.Seq`. See `Seq` [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq):

> Sequences are special cases of iterable collections of class Iterable. Unlike iterables, sequences always have a defined order of elements.

So yes, you'll get the same elements order with `foreach` and with loop + `dequeue`.

If you don't trust documentation you could  take a look at implementation:

`Queue#foreach` is inherited from `IterableLike` and [implemented](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L71) like this:

```
def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = iterator.foreach(f)
```

`Queue#iterator` is [implemented](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala#L68) like this:

```
override def iterator: Iterator[A] = (out ::: in.reverse).iterator
```

And `Queue#dequeue` [returns](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala#L114) the first element of `out`, if any, or the last element of `in`. So you'll get the same elements order.

Comment: actually in this case I value the documentation more then the implementation, because I consider the documentation a promise that this behavior isn't just 'by accident' but actually indented and will stay that way.